# Best way to get an object count in CoreData in iOS

Tags: ios, core-data, count

as I have seen there are several possibilities to get an object count in core data(when I say an object count I mean the object count and just only the object count).
If I set `resultType` to `NSCountResultType`, then what is better to do, `executeFetchRequest:error:` or `countForFetchRequest:error:`? Does the values of `includesPropertyValues` and `includesSubentities` care?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you only want a count of the objects that a fetch request would retrieve, call NSManagedObject's `-countForFetchRequest:error:`. It's easy enough to tell whether setting `includesSubentities` to YES makes a difference -- try it both ways and see. However, if I wanted to be certain that *only* those objects matching the request were counted, I'd start by setting that property to NO.